# .NET Remoting: Exception "Value NULL" at RegisterWellKnownServiceType

Tags: c#, remoting

I'm new at .NET remoting and C#. I need a client/server application and want to handle this with .NET Remoting. I've wrote a class library for the remoting object, the EchoServer class, with some test methods.

The class library I've added to my server project in Visual Studio. The assembly "System.Runtime.Remoting" I've added, too.

The following is the code of my server:

```
        using System;
        using System.Collections.Generic;
        using System.ComponentModel;
        using System.Data;
        using System.Drawing;
        using System.Linq;
        using System.Text;
        using System.Windows.Forms;
        using System.Runtime.Remoting;
        using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels;
        using System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Tcp;
        using Remoting; //Namespace Lib

        namespace Server
         {
         public partial class Server : Form
{
    public Server()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        TcpChannel serverChannel = null;

        try
        {
            serverChannel = new TcpChannel(9998);
            lvStatus.Items.Add("Server is listening on port 8089...");

            string strIn = "";

            ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(serverChannel, true);

            RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(Type.GetType("Remoting.EchoServer, remoting_dll"), "Echo", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ChannelServices.UnregisterChannel(serverChannel);
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

}

If I start the server, I will get an exception:

The value cannot be NULL
Parametername: type

I've tried some other code of a tutorial, but I will get the same excetion, equal if the class for the remoting object is implented as a class library or it is as a class directly in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post implementation of Remoting?
I thing that your mistake is next:

> "Remoting.EchoServer, remoting_dll"

So, you should use Type.GetType correctly.

Example of working code:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Server();
}

static void Server()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Server started...");
    var httpChannel = new HttpChannel(9998);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(httpChannel);
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(Type.GetType("Server.Program+SomeClass"), "SomeClass", WellKnownObjectMode.SingleCall);
    Console.WriteLine("Press ENTER to quit");
    Console.ReadLine();
}

public interface ISomeInterface
{
    string GetString();
}

public class SomeClass : MarshalByRefObject, ISomeInterface
{
    public string GetString()
    {
        const string tempString = "ServerString";
        Console.WriteLine("Server string is sended: {0}", tempString);
        return tempString;
    }
}
```